# A jQuery "double" swipe and styles issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

After trying several ways to solve the issues, I couldn't so I decided to ask for help.
I'm doing a small app for phonegap and using jQuery mobile. http://jsfiddle.net/tronne/vh4266mu/1/

The problems are:

1. When you swipe in the mobile it's ok, but from a desktop once you swipe the box, the panel also appear. I've found a possible solution, not sure if it's the proper one but it's working:

   ```
   $(document).on("swipeleft swiperight", "#mouseSwipe1", function (e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
   });
   ```
2. Another with styles, I'm, not sure why I can't see the panel "test 3" inline with test 1 and test 2, I've tried changing all widths but still no luck
3. And another style issue, when you swipe to see the panels, the first time you see the panel is working correctly but in the second there's a black big row at the bottom.